# How can i set only value on react select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using react-select with the isMulti attribute on a form. For simplicity the data are the following

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

if i select the first two options and then i submit the form, the react-select field will have the following value

```
reactSelectField: [
   { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
   { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' }
]
```

how can i set the fieldValue to

```
reactSelectField: ['chocolate', 'strawberry']
```

which is actually the values of the options and not the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform values yourself using onChange and a form state

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);

<Select 
  options={options}
  value={values.map((value) => ({ 
    label: value, 
    value,
  })}
  onChange={(values) => { 
    setValues(values.map((option) => option.value));
  }}
/>
```

Or create your own wrapper to return the value in the format you expect

```
const MyMultiSelect = ({ values = [], options = [], onChange, ...props }) => (
  <Select 
    {...props} 
    value={values.map((value) => ({ 
      label: value, 
      value,
    })}
    options={options.map((value) => ({
      label: value,
      value,
    })}
    onChange={(values) => { 
      onChange(values.map((option) => option.value));
    }}
  />
)

// Usage
<MyMultiSelect
  options={["chocolate", "strawberry", "banana"]}
  values={["chocolate", "banana"]}
  onChange={(values) => {
    console.log(values); // ["chocolate", "banana"]
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I should also pass the values property i suppose

Comment: Yes, same for options, I added this to my answer